# how to get printf output from NUCLEO F091C board

Tags: c, windows, stm32, mbed

I can successfully compile and run the LED blinky example from my Windows-7 using mbed online IDE, which runs on my NUCLEO F091C board.

How can I implement printf?

There's an example 'Nucleo_printf' which outputs to serial.
However, I haven't found instruction on how to get serial from Nucleo to PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/SerialPC

Turns out, serial outputs through the Nucleo's USB port to a virtual COM port on Windows-7.